# How should I load a fxml into another fxml?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have some problem with loading a fxml.
What I want to do it that:
I have 4 fxml files: main.fxml, head.fxml, body.fxml and new.fxml
Main includes head and body (i.e. I included (NOT imported) head and body inside main).
When I click a button in head, I want to load new.fxml and cover the body.fxml 
I don't want to replace body.fxml with new.fxml. I just want to cover it.
Is there a possible way to achieve it?

Comment: Just to answer your question. Yes!!! To get a more detailed answer, please add details to your question. If possible post code, even better, write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See the [Nested Controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) section in the FXML reference document. If that doesn't give enough details, do as @ItachiUchiha suggests and post an MCVE.